# Must versionCode in the manifest change with every little update?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I want to make a small change to a line of code in my Android project that is already published, should I change both of `android:verionCode` and `android:versionName`?

Comment: if you want to republish in Cafe bazaar or play store, you must change versionCode

Comment: thanks bro. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:versionCode requires to be increased so your users can see there's an update and decide if they want to download it or not.

android:versionName is just for showing this is displayed.

In a very small update you can have

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
```

for complete info please read https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

Answer (score 0):

Version code needs to be incremented. Version name can be whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Play Store will just not accept your updated APK file, if you are not updating the version information of it.

So yes: for any change/re-upload of your APK you have to change these properties.

The versionCode is never show to the user, so you can just automatically increment it with any build by using for example the build number of your integration server or an incrementing version code of your repository.

With the version name you normally use the last digit of the version string to indicate the only minor changes/bug fixes have been made in this release.